# How would I convert the value of str(len(rows)) to an int?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, types

I am working on a web-scraping project on python using selenium, and because I am fairly new to python, I ran into an issue when trying to output the number of rows in a web table as an integer. The method I found online goes as follows:

```
table = driver.find_element(by = By.ID, value = 'webtable')
tableRows = table.find_elements(by = By.TAG_NAME, value = 'tr')
print('rows: ' + str(len(tableRows)))
```

When I run the program, it outputs a string that I cannot use in a function which would display a specific number of rows. For example:

```
print('rows: ' + str(len(tableRows)) - 1)
```

produces the error:

> ```
> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'
> ```

How can I avoid this?  I'm sure the solution is simple but I am still trying to get used to python and stuff like this stumps me. I tried replacing str with in and also wrapping the whole thing in an int but I still get errors

Comment: You probably mean: `print('rows: ' + str(len(tableRows) - 1))`, substracting 1 to the length before turning it into a string.

Answer (score 0):

Do:

```
print('rows:', len(tableRows) - 1)
```

When you pass multiple arguments to `print`, it will automatically convert them to strings and put spaces between them.  There's no need to explicitly convert the result of `len` to a `str` in order to print it.

If you want the whole thing as one string, use an f-string to convert the int (after you do the subtraction):

```
print(f'rows: {len(tableRows) - 1}')
```

If you *really* want to do it by using the `+` operator to concatenate strings, you can do it, but you need to make sure to convert the int value to a string *after* you've done math on it, which is just a matter of adjusting the parentheses so that you *first* subtract the two ints and *then* concatenate the two strings:

```
print('rows: ' + str(len(tableRows) - 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

`len(tableRows)` would return an integer.

As an example:

```
mylist = ["apple", "banana", "cherry"]
print(type(len(mylist))) # prints -> <class 'int'>
```

So to do the substruction, perform the operation `len(tableRows) -1`   and then convert into a *string* as follows:

```
print('rows: ' + str(len(tableRows) - 1))
```

Comment: This will raise a `TypeError` because you're trying to concatenate a `str` to an `int`.

Comment: @Samwise yes you were right, corrected it now